# Raspberry Pi won't bring up wlanX interface - multiple wireless interfaces

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, debian, raspberry-pi

Let me jump straight in.

I am using a raspberry pi 3 running latest version of raspbian (pixel) as a router/wifi hotspot

---

I have 3 wireless interfaces:

1. built in wifi interface (*brcmfmac*)
2. [TP-Link WN722](http://www.tp-link.com/us/download/TL-WN722N.html) for 2.4Ghz Wifi-AP (not working yet) (*ath9k_htc*)
3. [Comfast CF-912AC](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00W37XPPK) (*rtl88112au*)

purpose of each interface:

- wlan0 => 5Ghz hostapd daemon
- wlan1 => link to router (refer to `wpa_supplicant` in `interfaces` file)
- wlan2 => 2.4Ghz hostapd daemon (not operational)

*see bottom for more info*

---

**Problem:**

*This has been a frequent problem, I have had, with Raspberry Pi's*

I simply cannot bring up an interface `wlan0` and `wlan2`, and `wlan2` won't budge to configuration set in `/etc/network/interfaces`.

I have tried various commands to bring up these interfaces, of which none work:

```
$ sudo ifdown wlan0
ifdown: interface wlan0 not configured

$ sudo ifup wlan0
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Failed to bring up wlan0.

$ sudo ifdown wlan2
ifdown: interface wlan2 not configured

$ sudo ifup wlan2
Ignoring unknown interface wlan2=wlan2.
```

and with `wlan0` and `wlan2` being down seen from `ip addr`

```
`sudo ip link set wlan0 up`

`sudo ip link set wlan2 up`
```

which has no success in bringing up these interfaces (confirmed down state with `ip` tool).

---

**How did this happen:**

*Note: all was working previously, although I could never bring up my tp-link wifi adapter, the ath9k_htc, so I left it down*

1. I was busy configuring my raspberry pi to run a second hostapd daemon on `wlan2` (which I would have sorted out after - driver issue):

   - copied my working hostapd config and modified it for 2.4Ghz, saved into `/etc/hostapd` directory with a unique name.
2. I used `dnsmasq` as the dhcp server, where `dhcpcd` was disabled and stopped:

   - I configured `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` to also listen on interface `wlan2`, adding ip to listen on `192.168.4.254` (*not sure if needed*)
3. Lastly edited `/etc/default/hostapd.conf` and added the second `hostapd` config with a space separation mentioned [here](https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-994626-start-0.html)
4. Finally, called a restart on these 2 services

   `sudo service dnsmasq restart`

   `sudo service hostapd restart`

This is where everything went to hell.

calling `sudo service networking restart` brought down `wlan0` (existing 5ghz hostapd daemon) and I couldn't bring it up since, nor `wlan0`. However `eth0` and `wlan1` stayed up, i.e.

**In conlusion:**

I had a 5Ghz wifi hotspot, and attempted to create a 2.4Ghz hotspot, now I am in the hotseat with no hotspot

I removed all the settings (i.e. revert back to previous working state) but was unsuccessful.

*Note aswel: several reboot did not solve anything*

---

**The question:**

**1.** How do I bring up these interfaces

**2.** Why does this issue of not being able to bring up an interface occur when everything seems right

*p.s. let me know if I missed anything*

---

**More info:**

**my interfaces file:**

```
$ sudo cat /etc/network/interfaces

source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
    address 192.168.0.254
    subnet 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.8.254
    network 192.168.0.0
    broadcast 192.168.0.255

allow-hotplug wlan2
iface wlan0 inet static
    address 192.168.4.254
    subnet 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.8.254
    network 192.168.4.0
    broadcast 192.168.4.255

allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.254
    subnet 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.8.254
    network 192.168.1.0
    broadcast 192.168.1.255

allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet static
    address 192.168.8.254
    subnet 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.8.1
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

**The logs:**

running `sudo ip link set wlan0 down`

- `dmesg` reports:

  `n/a`
- but `/var/log/syslog` reports:

  Apr 24 20:47:09 gateway avahi-daemon[480]: Interface wlan0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.

  Apr 24 20:47:09 gateway avahi-daemon[480]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv4 with address 192.168.0.254.

  Apr 24 20:47:09 gateway avahi-daemon[480]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.0.254 on wlan0.

followed by running `sudo ip link set wlan0 up`

- `dmesg` reports:

  `IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready`
- but `/var/log/syslog` reports:

  Apr 24 20:50:06 gateway avahi-daemon[480]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv4 with address 192.168.0.254.

  Apr 24 20:50:06 gateway avahi-daemon[480]: New relevant interface wlan0.IPv4 for mDNS.

  Apr 24 20:50:06 gateway avahi-daemon[480]: Registering new address record for 192.168.0.254 on wlan0.IPv4.

  Apr 24 20:50:06 gateway kernel: [ 2964.213013] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready

**NIC status**

```
 $ ip addr

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:e5:67:fb brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.254/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::ba27:ebff:fee5:67fb/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 40:a5:ef:d9:9c:4f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.254/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global wlan0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: wlan1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:b0:32:ae brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.8.254/24 brd 192.168.8.255 scope global wlan1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::ba27:ebff:feb0:32ae/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 100
    link/none 
    inet 192.168.10.1 peer 192.168.10.2/32 scope global tun0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: tun1: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 100
    link/none 
    inet 192.168.11.1 peer 192.168.11.2/32 scope global tun1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
7: wlan2: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 90:f6:52:13:aa:82 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

**NIC Info**

```
$ sudo lshw -C net

  *-usb:1                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: USB2.0 WLAN
       vendor: ATHEROS
       physical id: 2
       bus info: usb@1:1.2
       logical name: wlan2
       version: 1.08
       serial: 12345
       capabilities: usb-2.00 ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k_htc driverversion=4.4.50-v7+ firmware=1.3 link=no maxpower=500mA multicast=yes speed=480Mbit/s wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
  *-usb:2
       description: Wireless interface
       product: 802.11n NIC
       vendor: Realtek
       physical id: 5
       bus info: usb@1:1.5
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 0.00
       serial: 123456
       capabilities: usb-2.00 ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8812au ip=192.168.0.254 maxpower=500mA multicast=yes speed=480Mbit/s wireless=unassociated
  *-network:0
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: eth0
       serial: b8:27:eb:e5:67:fb
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=smsc95xx driverversion=22-Aug-2005 duplex=full firmware=smsc95xx USB 2.0 Ethernet ip=192.168.1.254 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
  *-network:1
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 3
       logical name: wlan1
       serial: b8:27:eb:b0:32:ae
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=brcmfmac driverversion=7.45.41.26 firmware=01-df77e4a7 ip=192.168.8.254 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
```

Comment: I know it is late... but there is an error in the interfaces file, the gateway cannot be outside the network. The only interface that should have a gateway is the `wlan1`

Comment: @JorgeValentini So there were an error in my interfaces file which had a part of (if not the actual) problem. Where I specify the `wlan2`, I set `wlan0` right below it. Thus, `wlan2` will never be set. Regarding the gateway, the setup (besides the issue mentioned prior) is correct. wlan0 is an adapter that connects to a wifi AP. wlan 1 and wlan2 are 'repeaters' of sorts, on 2.4Ghz and 5Ghz bands respectively, including eth0 which is a LAN 'repeater'. Strange setup, but it does work (and still works). I should maybe create a post about it, giving some details how to setup such a network.

Comment: Hi @Cybex, I am sorry, I should have tested thoroughly, I guess what I mean is that, while it may work, setting up the default gateway the same in all the interfaces is just not the way it should be, the routing table is not something that is assigned to an interface. if you run `ip route show`, you will probably see the gateway just once, and sourced from wlan1, but just because your OS is smart enough to interpret the conf like that.

Comment: But an interface by itself cannot have a gateway that is in a network it cannot reach. I hope that makes sense. Moreover, while you could have multiple default gateways, they are supposed to have different metrics for them.

Answer (score 0):

So I after some time, I found out that Raspbian uses the ifupdown package which you can manually download from [here](https://pkgs.org/download/ifupdown).

So the reason for your interface not coming up can vary, thus I cannot tell you what is the cause, but the logs CAN definitely help you if Googled.

**Get the Logs**

TO find these logs, use either this for a quick status update:

```
systemctl status networking.service
```

or this for detailed logs:

```
journalctl -u networking.service
```

**About `networking.service`**

You can find the service file here `/lib/systemd/system/networking.service`

Open it using nano/vim (I prefer nano) to view

The service runs `/sbin/ifup -a --read-environment`, but you can add additional verbosity `-v` to get more information about your network interfaces

Thus, running `/sbin/ifup -a --read-environment -v` will give you insight into why the interfaces cannot be brought up.

You can find an example output of the above command [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwE8u.png), from this [AskUbuntu post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/824376/failed-to-start-raise-network-interfaces-after-upgrading-to-16-04)